# How do I load my CSS while using gohtml templates and a golang webserver

Tags: html, css, go, go-templates

After re-arranging my file structure I can't seem to figure out how to get my CSS to load along with my gohtml pages.

My file structure looks like this:

```
my-app/
├── src/
│   ├── main.go
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── go.sum
├── www/
│   ├── styles/
│   │   └──style.css
│   └── pages/
│       └──index.gohtml
├── .env
└── README.md
```

The code that I use to load and serve the pages:

```
http.Handle("/www/", http.StripPrefix("/www/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("www"))))
http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var index = NewView("bootstrap", "../www/pages/index.gohtml")
    index.Render(w, nil)
}

http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
```

The code for `NewView()` in case needed:

```
var LayoutDir string = "../www/pages"

func NewView(layout string, files ...string) *View {
    files = append(layoutFiles(), files...)
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return &View{
        Template: t,
        Layout:   layout,
    }
}

type View struct {
    Template *template.Template
    Layout   string
}

func (v *View) Render(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}) error {
    return v.Template.ExecuteTemplate(w, v.Layout, data)
}

func layoutFiles() []string {
    files, err := filepath.Glob(LayoutDir + "/*.gohtml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return files
}
```

In my gohtml pages I link the css as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
```

I've got the CSS working before with the following file structure, however I wish to use the new structure.

```
my-app/
  www/
    styles/
      style.css
    pages/
      index.gohtml
  .env
  README.md
  main.go
  go.mod
  go.sum
```

I've tried changing the paths to a lot of different options but none of them have worked so far.

---EDIT 1
Changed the link href to `/styles/navbar.css` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: You use `StripPrefix` but still have `www` in the URL of the `link` tag.

Comment: Edited this but the problem still persists

Comment: where is your location path when you run command? `my-app` or `my-app/src`

Comment: I used `os.Getwd()` to get the following location path: `C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\GoProjects\my-app\src`